# How to make this dropdown menu full width underneath the navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a basic Bootstrap navbar [here](http://www.bootply.com/iBcL6GIQSm)

What I want to do is this:

> (Navbar)
>
> -----Logo------Item----Dropdown----------------------------Login/Signup-----
>
> (Dropdown menu)
>
> -----Sub-item----Sub-item----Sub-item---------------------------------------

On hover I want to make the dropdown menu show full width right underneath the navbar. The hover event isn't what I'm having trouble with, I'm having trouble positioning it correctly to be full 100% width.

**Update**

I see that bootstrap adds `position: relative` to `.nav > li`, when I take that off in Chrome developer tools it goes full width off the screen starting at the position of the navbar element.

**Solution**

[Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/MhEn027pSZ)

The solution to my example was overriding Bootstrap's `.nav>li` to `position: static`.

I now know that this is called a mega menu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know exactly what you need if my thought is right you want this link , check with the bootstrap mega menu

[click here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-mega-menu)

Comment: Ah! It would help if I knew the proper terminology for it. Yes that's exactly what I wanted. I was able to fix my example by overriding `.nav>li` to `position: static`. Posted the updated one in my question. This is very useful thanks.